# Xpath to get href that contain id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all links that contain ids.I have tried for name and price which is working perfectly but not able to get links which is related to that stuff.

> > For name I am using this code but for getting links it is not working.

```
//For Name
 var name=scorenodesdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[contains(@id,'item')]/ul[1]/li1]/span");
//for Links
var Links= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@id, 'item')]/@href");
```

> > xpath for link is://*[@id="item5d86882c07"]/div[1]/div/a

//This is the code I am try to get the href link

```
<li id="item5d86882c07" _sp="p2045573.m1686.l8" listingid="401689029639" class="sresult lvresult clearfix li" r="1">

    <div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="401689029639">
            <div class="lvpicinner full-width picW">

    <a href="https://www.ebay.com/itm/Microsoft-Xbox-One-X-White-Console-1TB-Forza-Special-Edition-Bundle-White/401689029639?hash=item5d86882c07:g:lgwAAOSwoZJcQY5s" class="img imgWr2">
<img src="https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/lgwAAOSwoZJcQY5s/s-l225.jpg" class="img" alt="Microsoft Xbox One X White Console 1TB &amp; Forza Special Edition Bundle - White'">
    </a>
            </div>
  </div>


</li>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question : in your example HTML, your `<a>` doesn't have an attribute `id=...`. Do you want an xpath for it? Also, are you sure you show all the relevant HTML? And is the first xpath you show 'for names' somehow relevant to the question?

Comment: @Pac0 yes but when right click on the code to copy xpath  gives us //*[@id="item5d86882c07"]/div[1]/div/a. Yes because it is in the li tag which contain id.eg <li id="5475"

Comment: There is no `li` tag in your example. Please consider writing something close to a [mcve], so we can understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @Pac0 I have update my question,on li tag you can see eg: id="item4687" .For getting name I am using this "//[contains(@id,'item')]/ul[1]/li1]/span" .similirarly I want to get href link like that.It would be nice if you also help to get the image link too.Actually I am using two column separately for redirect link to get detail of product and second column for image.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarifications. Is `//a[contains(@href, 'item')]/@href` better, maybe ?

Comment: @Pac0 its getting just name of the product not link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186973/discussion-between-adil-yar-and-pac0).

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is how I resolve my issue.First it gets get anchor tag information then by using getattributevalue to get value of href.

```
var URLnodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@id,'item')]/div[1]/div/a");
var AllURL = URLnodes.Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href",null));
```